# Does Pgbench modify the database?

Tags: postgresql, locks, pgbench

I'm trying to generate "locks" in my postgresql database, i used pgbench to create an activity in the database while lanching a vacuum full or reindex to generate some process "locks" and nothing happened ...

so i'm not sure if pgbench creates a "real" activity in the database,

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Without arguments, pgbench just runs 10 small transactions and exits.  This takes very little time and is pretty much useless.  You will almost always want to at least specify some largish value for -T or -t.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html)

> By default, pgbench tests a scenario that is loosely based on TPC-B, involving five SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT commands per transaction